# How do I remove everything before "text:"?

Tags: vba, excel

I have this kind of of data in my Excel sheet. Some might not even have "text":

> {asdd":"pagasasse","qqwqwqww":"acc-96d032ef-3cef-d692-9daa-05f08106e999","pusherevent":"eve-96d032ef-3cef-d692-9daa-05f08106e999","entry":[{"id":"122222222","time":1493375728269,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"96d032ef-3cef-d692-9daa-05f08106e999"},"recipient":{"id":"598113966995478"},"timestamp":1493375727943,"message":{"mid":"mid.$cAAE_a0qfMcxh5WaBR1btCE7pLG5M","seq":24608,"text":"form __load  F6910BF04A294FA59A89E398EF4B2E09"}}]}]}"

How would I remove everything before "text":

Comment: Please, format the output .  And considere to try yourself and post the code.

Comment: This can be achieved using Excel functions only (`RIGHT`, `LEN`, `FIND`). Are you open to that?

Comment: Have a look at [InStr Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/InStr-Function-85d3392c-3b1c-4232-bb18-77cd0cb8a55b) for a VBA solution or have a look at the Excel formulas `=FIND()`, `=RIGHT` and `=LEFT` to start on your own.

Comment: @Trimax I need output in the form "text":"whatever inside". 
I tried using regex .But i could not figure out.

Comment: Your desired output in your example would be "form __load  F6910BF04A294FA59A89E398EF4B2E09"? Also, what have you tried so far and where did you get stuck? SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: @RikSportel Yes exactly that is the intended output .
I used regex to remove that piece but stuck in copying to another column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A formula to achieve this result from having the value in A1 would be:

`=IFERROR(LEFT(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("""text"":",A1,1)-7),FIND("""",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("""text"":",A1,1)-7),1)-1),"text not found")`

A VBA equivalent would be:

```
Function GetTextValue(str As String) As String
    Dim tmpstr As String
    If InStr(1, str, """text"":", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        GetTextValue = "Text not found"
    Else
        tmpstr = Right(str, Len(str) - InStr(1, str, """text"":", vbTextCompare) - 7)
        tmpstr = Left(tmpstr, InStr(1, tmpstr, """", vbTextCompare) - 1)
        GetTextValue = tmpstr
    End If
End Function
```

Which you can call as:

```
Sub test()
Dim str as string
str = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").value
str = GetTextValue(str)
ActiveSheet.Range("B1").value = str
End Sub
```

Or use in a cell as: `=GetTextValue(A1)`